# Class design for domain model with audit trail

Tags: java, php, oop

This is my DB design:

```
Person
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
Name              VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
DOB               DATE NOT NULL,
Email             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL


Person_History
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
PersonID          UINT NOT NULL,
Name              VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
DOB               DATE NOT NULL,
Email             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
AuditID           UINT NOT NULL


Audit
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
UserID            UINT NOT NULL,               -- Who
AffectedOn        DATE NOT NULL,               -- When
Comment           VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL        -- Why
```

I would like to be able to reuse most of the person code for the person history class, since the properties are duplicated.  With the way it is now, should I be factoring out and encapsulating the person properties?  This way, I can use composition, instead of having to duplicate code between a Person class and a PersonHistory class?

Comment: Did you really mean Java or probably JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should avoid duplicating your DB columns in my opinion it should be:

```
Person
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
Name              VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
DOB               DATE NOT NULL,
Email             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL


Person_History
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
PersonID          UINT NOT NULL,
AuditID           UINT NOT NULL


Audit
------------------------------------------------
ID                UINT NOT NULL,
UserID            UINT NOT NULL,               -- Who
AffectedOn        DATE NOT NULL,               -- When
Comment           VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL        -- Why
```

In case you're using JPA your classes could be mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "DOB")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PersonHistory> personHistories;

// getters and setters...

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_HISTORY")
public class PersonHistory {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PERSON", nullable=false)
private Person person;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_AUDIT", nullable=false)
private Audit audit;

// getters and setters...

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "AUDIT")
public class Audit {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "AFFECTED_ON")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date affectedOn;

@Column(name = "COMMENT")
private String comment;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_USER", nullable=false)
private User user;

// getters and setters...

}
```

So in your object model you will be able to access Person data from Person History.

Comment: wouldn't this clog the person table, since there would be a mix of current and historical data?

Comment: In your DB Person table will only be storing Person related fields, so each entity will be storing on it's own table the data which it is concerned with no redundancy, no duplicated columns across tables, can you point out an example of this mix of current and historical data?